# ZonedDateTimeDeserializer is missing in jackson jsr310

Tags: java, jaxb, jackson, date-parsing, zoneddatetime

I'm parsing a `ZonedDateTime` using like this:

```
 @JsonSerialize(using = ZonedDateTimeSerializer.class)
 private ZonedDateTime expirationDateTime;
```

I need to be able to properly deserialize this date. However, there is no deserializer for this that is provided by jackson:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser
```

Is there a reason why it's missing? What is the most common workaround?

**Updated**:
Here is my scenario:

I create `ZonedDateTime` like this:

```
ZonedDateTime.of(2017, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

Then I serialize the object that contains the date like this:

```
public static String toJSON(Object o) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    StringWriter sWriter = new StringWriter();
    try {
        JsonGenerator jsonGenerator = objectMapper.getJsonFactory().createJsonGenerator(sWriter);
        objectMapper.writeValue(jsonGenerator, o);
        return sWriter.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}
```

And when I try to send it to Spring MVC Controller:

```
    mockMvc.perform(post("/endpoint/")
            .content(toJSON(myObject))
            .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

The date object that goes inside the controller is different.

Before: `2017-01-01T01:01:01.000000001Z`

After: `2017-01-01T01:01:01.000000001Z[UTC]`

Comment: Jackson by default uses the `InstantDeserializer` class for `ZonedDateTime` objects, so it should work. I've made a simple test here and it deserialized the value without any additional configuration. If you have tested and it didn't work, though, you can [edit] the question and add this info to it.

Comment: Yes, just a minute.

Comment: How is the deserilzation code in the controller? Do you also use object mapper or it's configured in Spring?

Comment: Spring boot does it, But, I can see that it even happens when I convert object to/from json via object mapper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 2 values `2017-01-01T01:01:01.000000001Z` and `2017-01-01T01:01:01.000000001Z[UTC]` actually represent the same instant, so they are equivalent and can be used without a problem (at least there **should** be no problems as they represent the same instant).

The only detail is that Jackson, for some reason, sets the `ZoneId` value to "UTC" when deserializing, which is redundant in this case (the `Z` already tells that the offset is "UTC"). But it shouldn't affect the date value itself.

---

A very simple way to get rid of this `[UTC]` part is to convert this object to `OffsetDateTime` (so it keeps the `Z` offset and don't use the `[UTC]` zone) and then back again to `ZonedDateTime`:

```
ZonedDateTime z = // object with 2017-01-01T01:01:01.000000001Z[UTC] value
z = z.toOffsetDateTime().toZonedDateTime();
System.out.println(z); // 2017-01-01T01:01:01.000000001Z
```

After that, the value of `z` variable will be `2017-01-01T01:01:01.000000001Z` (without the `[UTC]` part).

But of course this is not ideal as you'd have to do it manually for all dates. A better approach is to write a custom deserializer (by extending `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.InstantDeserializer`) that don't set the timezone when it's **UTC**:

```
public class CustomZonedDateTimeDeserializer extends InstantDeserializer<ZonedDateTime> {
    public CustomZonedDateTimeDeserializer() {
        // most parameters are the same used by InstantDeserializer
        super(ZonedDateTime.class,
              DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME,
              ZonedDateTime::from,
              // when zone id is "UTC", use the ZoneOffset.UTC constant instead of the zoneId object
              a -> ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(a.value), a.zoneId.getId().equals("UTC") ? ZoneOffset.UTC : a.zoneId),
              // when zone id is "UTC", use the ZoneOffset.UTC constant instead of the zoneId object
              a -> ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochSecond(a.integer, a.fraction), a.zoneId.getId().equals("UTC") ? ZoneOffset.UTC : a.zoneId),
              // the same is equals to InstantDeserializer
              ZonedDateTime::withZoneSameInstant, false);
    }
}
```

Then you have to register this deserializer. If you use `ObjectMapper`, you need to add this to the `JavaTimeModule`:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JavaTimeModule module = new JavaTimeModule();
// add my custom deserializer (this will affect all ZonedDateTime deserialization)
module.addDeserializer(ZonedDateTime.class, new CustomZonedDateTimeDeserializer());
objectMapper.registerModule(module);
```

If you configure it in Spring, the config will be something like this (*not tested*):

```
<bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean" id="pnxObjectMapper">
    <property name="deserializersByType">
        <map key-type="java.lang.Class">
            <entry>
                <key>
                    <value>java.time.ZonedDateTime</value>
                </key>
                <bean class="your.app.CustomZonedDateTimeDeserializer">
                </bean>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I wish it was built-in feature in the library. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I use this :

```
        JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
    javaTimeModule.addSerializer(ZonedDateTime.class, new ZonedDateTimeSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME));
    javaTimeModule.addDeserializer(ZonedDateTime.class, InstantDeserializer.ZONED_DATE_TIME);
```