# Java 8 Exception: com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.InstantDeserializer has no default (no arg) constructor

Tags: java, json, jackson, fasterxml, jsr310

I have a model class that has a field:

```
 @JsonDeserialize(using = InstantDeserializer.class)
 @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
 private OffsetDateTime offsetDt;
```

When a request of this model is sent to the server, my controller throws an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Class com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.InstantDeserializer 
has no default (no arg) constructor
```

The pom.xml has the dependency of version 2.8.11:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I understand that it is caused by @JsonDeserialize requiring no-arg constructor, but is there a workaround?

Comment: `InstantDeserializer.class` is custom deserializer class?, if i believe in that class you may declared some arg constructor without no-arg constructor

Comment: @Deadpool no, it is not a custom class..   com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser

Comment: what does your POM look like?

Comment: @DarrenForsythe  Just updated above with the dependency.  Were you looking for something else in the pom.xml?

Comment: Have you tried `@JsonDeserialize(using = InstantDeserializer.INSTANT)` instead?

Comment: @JulioDanielReyes   I just tried and I got a compiler error -- Type mismatch: cannot convert from InstantDeserializer<Instant> to Class<? extends JsonDeserializer>

Comment: Look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45215515/4727666, you need a class with a constructor that takes no arguments, so you can extend InstantDeserializer to create your own.

Comment: For the arguments, take a look at this https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/deser/InstantDeserializer.java#L53

Comment: @JulioDanielReyes  Thank you very much.  I will take a look

Comment: @JulioDanielReyes  still doesn't work after adding the constructor.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error says that you need a class with no arg constructor, so you could extend from `InstantDeserializer`. (Take as example the code in [`InstantDeserializer`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/deser/InstantDeserializer.java#L62) for the arguments of `super()`)

```
public class DefaultInstantDeserializer extends InstantDeserializer<OffsetDateTime> {
    public DefaultInstantDeserializer() {
        super(OffsetDateTime.class, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME,
                OffsetDateTime::from,
                a -> OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(a.value), a.zoneId),
                a -> OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochSecond(a.integer, a.fraction), a.zoneId),
                (d, z) -> d.withOffsetSameInstant(z.getRules().getOffset(d.toLocalDateTime())),
                true);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = DefaultInstantDeserializer.class)
```